# floatrow.sty error; line 485; No room for a new \dimen . ...finable\flrow@foot{\newinsert\flrow@foot}

Tags: floatrow

- I get "floatrow.sty error; line 485; No room for a new \dimen . ...finable\flrow@foot{\newinsert\flrow@foot}"
- The code used is given below. Any help to solve this is highly appreciated. Adding \usepackage{etex} didn't help

```
%\pdfminorversion=4

\documentclass[twoside]{article}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage[]{graphicx}
\usepackage[noabbrev]{cleveref}
\usepackage[font={it},tableposition={top}]{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{xfrac}
\usepackage[hmarginratio=1:1,top=32mm,columnsep=0.2in]{geometry} % Document margins
\usepackage{multicol} % Used for the two-column layout of the document
\usepackage[style=boxed,font=small]{floatrow}
\usepackage{array,booktabs} % Horizontal rules in tables
\usepackage{float} % Required for tables and figures in the multi-column environment - they need to be placed in specific locations with the [H] (e.g. \begin{table}[H])
\usepackage{paralist} % Used for the compactitem environment which makes bullet points with less space between them
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[figuresright]{rotating}
\usepackage{xfrac}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{import}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[rightcaption]{sidecap}
\usepackage{cite}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,pgfplots.groupplots}
    \tikzset{arrow/.style={
            -stealth, thick
        }}
\allowdisplaybreaks 
\pgfplotsset{
    legend image with text/.style={
        legend image code/.code={%
            \node[anchor=center] at (0.3cm,0cm) {#1};
        }
    },
}

\floatsetup[table]{capposition=top}
\newsavebox{\tempbox}
\newcommand*\diff{\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}}
\newcommand*\Diff[1]{\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d^#1}}
\DeclareSymbolFont{extraup}{U}{zavm}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\vardiamond}{\mathalpha}{extraup}{87}
\DeclareSIUnit\torr{Torr}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\maketitle}{\bgroup\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
    \begin{flushleft}
        \textbf{\@title}
        \vspace*{0.5cm}
        \@author
    \end{flushleft}\egroup
}
\makeatother

\titleformat{\subsection}[hang]{}{\thesubsection}{1em}{\itshape}
\titleformat{\subsubsection}[runin]{}{\thesubsubsection}{1em}{\itshape}
\bibliographystyle{iopart-num}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{document}
\begin{abstract}
\textit{In situ} 
\end{abstract}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I can compile this without errors. Are you sure this is the correct document?

Comment: Shifting the floatrow up in the order helped solve the problem :)

Comment: \usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage[style=boxed,font=small]{floatrow}
\usepackage{xfrac}

Comment: Thanks @ChristianHupfer for the offer to help. Just rearranging helped.

Comment: @MKG What TeX distribution are you using?

Comment: You should not get this error with a current latex (although it's a bug in floatrow)